# Why is RandomForestClassifier of scikit-learn not deterministic in explicit setup?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, random-forest

I would like to know why RandomForestClassifiers I create in Python using scikit-learn produce different results when I repeat learning on the same data set. Can someone explain this to me please?

The relevant part of my code is this:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier as RFC
RFC(n_estimators=100, max_features=None, criterion="entropy", bootstrap=False)
```

This setup should actually prevent any randomness, right? It should force the algorithm to use the same amount of data instances (which is the complete data set) for every base learner to grow and to consider every feature for every split.

One explaination I got is this: Maybe the algorithm keeps some randomness in how the features are taken out of the set of all features, e.g.:

- Given are features f1 and f2
- For a split in node 1 the algorithm chooses f1 and afterwards f2 to consider for this split
- Both features might have the same split quality and f1 is picked first as it was drawn first
- For a split in node 2 the algorithm might as well choose f2 first and f1 afterwards and therefore the model created can differ from other models created by that algorithm

Can anyone give reliable information?

Answer (score 2):

No, that set-up will not guarantee reproducible results.  You've detailed exactly the case that happens with most RF implementations: the random splits depend on the seed to the random number function.

To control that, look in the documentation to find which random-number package your ML algorithm uses.  You can likely import that package and force a value to the **seed** method.  If you want to try for a quick solution, try

```
import random
random.seed(<value>)
```

... where  is any hashable constant of your choice.  I recommend an integer or string you like.  I suggest this because I suspect that your RF package uses the Python **random** package -- giving this a try might save you the trouble of poring over documentation.

Most packages will use the system time as the default seed; that's to make *sure* you get varying results.

Comment: Thank you for your time and answer, Prune!
Yes, the seed will of course "solve" this issue by making the algorithm deterministic. The trouble is I have a very special problem to address and I can't afford to pass a seed. Did you try to express all randomness that is left in the described setup is as I have described in the example?

Comment: Btw. the RF-constructor offers the parameter random_state to define a seed.

Comment: Ah; I see the coverage you're describing.  However, I still believe that your bulleted steps define exactly the case where you'll get differing results from a series of runs.  Can you test that hypothesis with a set of features in which no two features can have the same split quality?

Comment: Interesting idea, thanks, I'll consider this when I start working on my project tomorrow. (My trouble is I have only very little time left to work on this project and have to be quick so I can't afford to investigate this issue for too long.)